# How can I prove this statement about square root?

Tags: induction, roots, formal-languages

**Introduction**

In computer science there is a field called Formal Methods and Specifications. In this field software designers design softwares by specifying their functionalities in formal methods, for example in set theory.

---

**Problem**

In this field a program that calculates square root of a number is specified by

\begin{align}
\forall a  \in \mathbb{N} \cdot \exists b \in \mathbb{N} \cdot (b \times b \le a) \land (a <  (b+1) \times (b+1))
\end{align}

where in this formula, `a` is program's input and `b` is program's output. Now I want to prove this statement by induction on `a`. As such, I should show that this statement is true for `a = 0` and if this is true for `a = x`, I should prove that this is also true for `a = x + 1`.

Also proofs other than Induction is also okay.

For induction, I do not know how should I prove this statement for `a = x + 1` when this statements holds for `a = x`

Comment: It seems like a weird thing to prove by induction.  Indeed $[0,1]$, $[1,4]$, $[4,9]$, $[9,16]$, $\dots$  partition $[0,\infty)$.  So any $a$ must land in one of these intervals.  QED.

Comment: @GregoryGrant I see, this looks pretty obvious, but we should prove it in a _formal_ way.

Comment: Using a partition in this way is considered rigorous in mathematics.  I don't know about computer science.  What would be the non-rigorous part of my argument that would need to be fixed?  Just say $[0^2,1^2]$ $[1^2,2^2]$, $[2^2,3^2]$, $\dots$ is a partition so any $a$ *has* to be in one such interval.  I'm pretty sure this would be considered rigorous in the math world.

Comment: @GregoryGrant You are absolutely right, your proof is fully acceptable in math world. But in my case proof must be done only by algebra calculus and predicate logic -- I am not allowed to use natural language to prove this statements.

Comment: How about the following then: $\mathbb R^+=\cup_{n=0}^\infty[n^2,(n+1)^2]$, $\therefore$ $b\in\mathbb R^+$ $\Rightarrow$ $b\in\cup_{n=0}^\infty[n^2,(n+1)^2]$ $\Rightarrow$ $\exists$ $n\in\mathbb R$ $\wedge$ $b\in[n^2,(n+1)^2]$.  QED.

Comment: @GregoryGrant This one seems very good. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome!

Comment: The requirement is not for a _rigorous_ proof; it is for a _formal_ proof. I'd expect there to be a predetermined set of inference rules that may be applied, much like in an automated theorem-proving system. Without knowing the inference rules that are available, I don't think one can just solve the problem, but I can think of hints.

Comment: @DavidK Thanks for the clarifications.  I only ever do proofs in the math domain so this whole thing of "formal" proofs is a mystery to me.

Comment: @DavidK Yes, there are a bunch of rules that I didn't mention them in the question text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the induction step, you assume that $a \in \mathbb{N}$
and that $$\exists b \in \mathbb{N} . (b \times b \le a) \land (a <  (b+1) \times (b+1)). \tag{1}$$

Now, depending on exactly how your formal system is formulated,
there should be some way to identify a *witness* for $(1)$, that is,
for the inductive step you can introduce a free variable $b_0$ and
assume that $(b_0 \times b_0 \le a) \land (a <  (b_0+1) \times (b_0+1)).$

For $a + 1$, then, there are two cases. 
In one case, $a + 1 < (b_0 + 1) \times (b_0 + 1).$
You can then prove (via some additional formal steps)
that $(b_0 \times b_0 \le a + 1)$, and therefore that
$$\exists b \in \mathbb{N} . (b \times b \le a+1) \land (a+1 <  (b+1) \times (b+1)).$$

In the other case, $a + 1 \geq (b_0 + 1) \times (b_0 + 1).$
If you can then prove (via additional formal steps)
that $(a < ((b_0+1)+1) \times ((b_0+1)+1)),$
these two inequalities establish that
$$\exists b \in \mathbb{N} . (b \times b \le a + 1) \land 
(a + 1 <  (b+1) \times (b+1)), \tag{2}$$
using $b_0 + 1$ as a witness for $b$.

You then need at least one more formal step in order to combine the
conclusions of the two cases so that you can state formula $(2)$
outside the context of either case,
that is, in a context where you have assumed only
$a \in \mathbb N$ and formula $(1)$, to complete the inductive step.

This is merely a strategy for the proof.
Obviously you will need to produce a sequence of formal inferences;
the details depend on exactly what inferential tools you are allowed to use
and on the way in which they have been formulated.